# Setting the default date for html 5 date type with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, date

i have to set the today,s date as default in html date type , i am able to do that as this check this working fiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/irfanshafi/v1ex6v4g/) , But its not working when i am changing the ng-model to        `my.date`

```
    <input type="date" ng-model="my.date" value={{my.date}}>
    //angular controller
     function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
     $scope.my.date = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

why so ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.my` is `undefined` and you are trying to assign the property `date` to it - that's why it doesn't work. Instead, define it like so:

```
$scope.my = {};
$scope.my.date = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Or, equivalently.

```
$scope.my = {date: $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put variables inside object, you need to declare that object first.

In your controller declare the **$scope.my** object first.

**HTML**

```
<input type="date" ng-model="my.date" >
```

**Controller JS**

```
$scope.my = {};
    $scope.my.date = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

***You don't need to set the value in input. Once the value of ng-model is set, it is bind to input field.***

[Updated  JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1ex6v4g/4/)